# Switch value not updating in renderRow

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a key value array in my state containing booleans indicating the value of my switches.

When I trigger the Switch component, the value is correctly changed in my state but the value of my Switch stays the same. It's like the component is not updated. I did the exact same thing in another project and it is working there.

```
_changeValue(k) {
    switchesValues[k] = !switchesValues[k]
    this.setState({
      switches: switchesValues
    })
}

_renderEventRow(allergiesList) {
    var k = allergiesList.key

    return (
      <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', height: 50, alignItems: 'center', paddingLeft: 10, borderBottomWidth: 0.5, borderColor: 'lightgray'}}>
        <Text style={{flex: 1, color: '#5f5f5f'}}>{allergiesList.name}</Text>
        <Switch style={{marginRight: 10}} value={this.state.switches[k]} onValueChange={() => this._changeValue(k)}/>
      </View>
    )
}
```

My list view :

```
var ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 != r2})

constructor(props) {
super(props)
    this.state = {
      ds:[],
      dataSource:ds,
      switches: []
    }
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(this.state.ds),
    })
    this.findAllergies()
}

render() {
    return(
      <ListView
        dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
        renderRow={(rowData) => { return this._renderEventRow(rowData)}}
      />)}
    )
}

findAllergies() {
  var that = this
  firebase.database().ref("allergies").on("value", (snap) => {
    var items = [];

    snap.forEach((child) => {
      items.push({
        name: child.val(),
        key: child.key,
      })
    })

    that.setState({
      dataSource: that.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(items),
    });
  })
}
```

Comment: post the code of ListView and how you set the data to listView

Comment: edited my first post with the code of my ListView

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have created a sample app to implement your requirement. Have a look at the below code.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
    AppRegistry,
    Text,
    View,
    TouchableOpacity,
    Switch,
    ListView,
} from 'react-native';

var ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 != r2});

export default class AwesomeProject extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            ds: [],
            dataSource: ds,
            switches: []
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        let allergies = [];
        this.switchesValues = [];
        for (let i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
            allergies.push({
                key: i,
                name: 'Name ' + i,
            });
            this.switchesValues[i] = false;
        }
        this.setState({
            dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(allergies),
            switches: this.switchesValues,
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <ListView
                dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
                renderRow={(rowData) => { return this._renderEventRow(rowData)}}
            />);
    }

    _changeValue(k) {
        console.log('Status '+JSON.stringify(this.switchesValues))
        this.switchesValues[k] = !this.switchesValues[k];
        this.setState({
            switches: this.switchesValues,
        })
    }

    _renderEventRow(allergiesList) {
        var k = allergiesList.key

        return (
            <View
                style={{flexDirection: 'row', height: 50, alignItems: 'center', paddingLeft: 10, borderBottomWidth: 0.5, borderColor: 'lightgray'}}>
                <Text style={{flex: 1, color: '#5f5f5f'}}>{allergiesList.name}</Text>
                <Switch style={{marginRight: 10}} value={this.state.switches[k]}
                        onValueChange={() => this._changeValue(k)}/>
            </View>
        )
    }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('AwesomeProject', () => AwesomeProject);
```